# Will_paginate gem is not installing - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, will-paginate

for something reason will_paginate is not installed.

i have put the line

```
gem 'will_paginate', '~>3.0.6'
```

in my gemfile,

i even ran "gem install will_paginate" in the console.

it says installed sucessfully but using the instructions to check if will_paginate is indeed install returns false nil

reference:

```
>> defined? WillPaginate
>> ActiveRecord::Base.respond_to? :paginate
If any of these lines return nil/false, will_paginate has not properly loaded in your app.
```

and i get this error when implemented

```
undefined method `total_pages' for #<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fa40773bc18>
```

UPDATE:

I specifically stated in my gemfile to install version 3.0.5 not the latest version(3.0.7) and the gem is loaded properly. BUT the error with the total_pages still remains.

more info:

controller:

```
@posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

view:

```
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

UPDATE 2:
FIXED the error (had a typo) BUT i cannot see visually the gem anywhere on the page.

Comment: continue to read the troubleshooting section: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Troubleshooting It has specific instructions for total_pages error

Comment: i did. Since will paginate is not loaded i cant look for total_pages yet.I need to fix the load error and hopefully the other error goes away too.

Comment: are you using the rails console? what is the error you are getting? (full stack trace)

Comment: see the 
reference i wrote above, troubleshooting says that if these two commands return nil or false then the gem is not loaded properly and thats exactly what they return

Comment: also something weird. if i run bundle install to install the gem. it says bundle complete but it makes no reference to what gem was installed.

Comment: Which rails/ruby are you using?

Comment: did you restart your server?

Comment: @dimakura using ruby version 2.2.1 and rails 4.2.1 , i have stated specifically to install 3.0.5 and now when i check that the gem is loaded it is indeed loaded. something weird with the last version i guess. But the `undefined method "total_pages" error` still remains. will continue troubleshoot.

Comment: @xprise yes i did many times!

Comment: It might be issue with Kaminari then. Check `bunle show kaminari`

Comment: @dimakura i had a typo actually but now i do not see anywhere visually the pagination on the page and no errors whatsoever

Comment: you need to put it on your views: `<%= paginate @posts %>` and you should have many posts (more then 1 page)

Comment: yes the problem was that i had less posts.